# No OPKernel was registered to support Op 'Equal' with these attrs

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, tensorflow

Im getting the following error when trying to load my TensorFlow model, im using the following tools:

Xcode (Latest)

TensorFlow Experimental V1.1.1 (Installed using pods)

C++

Im able to create the TensorFlow session with no issues, and I'm able to read the TensorFlow model into a GraphDef, but when I try to create the model using the active TensorFlow session I get the following issue.

> Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Equal' with these attrs.
>
> Registered devices:
>
> [CPU]
>
> Registered kernels:
>
> device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT] [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT32, _output_shapes=[[]]](Rank, Equal)]]

This is how my code currently looks

```
tensorflow::Session* sessionPointer = nullptr;
const tensorflow::SessionOptions options;

tensorflow::Status newSessionStatus = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &sessionPointer);

[MachineLearning checkTensorflowStatus:newSessionStatus];

std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(sessionPointer);

// Create a point to the tensorflow graph
tensorflow::GraphDef tensorflowGraph;

// Get the model file path
NSString* filePath = FilePathForResourceName(@"frozen_inference_graph", @"pb");

// Read the data into the TensorflowGraph
auto fileConverteredToProto = PortableReadFileToProto([filePath UTF8String], &tensorflowGraph);

// Create the tensorflow graph
tensorflow::Status createGraphStatus = session->Create(tensorflowGraph);

// Check the status of the tensorflow graph
[MachineLearning checkTensorflowStatus:createGraphStatus];
```

I have checked that the file path it is getting is correct and it seems fine with loading the model data into the GraphDef. This is how I do it

```
// Finds the file path for the given file name
NSString* FilePathForResourceName(NSString* name, NSString* extension)
{
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
    if (filePath == NULL)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Could not find the TensorFlow model";
    }
    return filePath;
}

// Reads the file into the protobuf. This was taken from the TensorFlow example code
bool PortableReadFileToProto(const std::string& fileName, ::google::protobuf::MessageLite* proto)
{
    // Create the input stream with the given file name
    ::google::protobuf::io::CopyingInputStreamAdaptor stream(new IfstreamInputStream(fileName));

    // Set that this object owns the copying stream
    stream.SetOwnsCopyingStream(true);

    // Create a coded input stream
    ::google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream codedStream(&stream);

    // Set the byte limit, aparently having protos too big can causes issues, so we limit it.
    codedStream.SetTotalBytesLimit(1024LL << 20, 512LL << 20);

    // Parse the coded stream
    return proto->ParseFromCodedStream(&codedStream);
}
```

I did some reading about OP's not been supported in other posts, but Equal is already supported but it doesn't work in the way that I need it too for my TensorFlow model.

I was also reading this guide on how to add a new OP.
[Tensorflow how to add a new OP](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op)

But I don't really understand how it all works, so im struggling to get my model running.

I would have preferred to convert my TensorFlow model to CoreML and used the Swift CoreML tools, but there is an issue with the conversion, where the Slice OP isn't fully supported and it can't convert my model.

Comment: Sounds like the freeze graph script created an invalid graph with one float and one int input to an `Equal` operation. Could you file a bug with the inputs to freeze_graph and instructions to run it (assuming that's where the GraphDef came from)? Your loading code is probably fine.